# Is there an OSMnx function to find the nearest building footprint to a geocoded address?

Tags: osmnx

Starting from a list of addresses of interest...

To find the nearest building footprint, using https://github.com/Microsoft/USBuildingFootprints seems like the best source, given a geocoded address, which is presumably a linear interpolation of a TIGER/Line file with an offset from the street.

I see that Google Maps does a pretty good job of locating their pin within the building footprint, but am trying to avoid going over my free limit, so I will probably use the [Census geocoder](https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/address?form).

The key function seems to be `osmnx.footprints.footprints_from_address`, but what is the definition of "within", the footprint is contained or footprint overlaps an arc of a given distance from the geocode?

There seem to be many ways to go wrong...

1. The house is set well back, and the neighbors are actually closer to the geocode, including houses on the other side of the street,
2. Gazebos, sheds, pop-up tents, large doghouses
3. other...

Is there a function or algorithm to at least eliminate the "other side of the street" issue?, maybe someone can mod the function so add same_side as a binary option, meaning "do not cross street segments"?

So, I am asking about strategy...
I am thinking to use some kind of half the average inter-building distance (buildings that are within a certain distance from the street, and at least a given size (i.e., houses)), by block or census tract (?, because, for a county or state, it could vary wildly) as an estimate of half of the lot width, and only looking for footprints within the lateral bounds of the presumed "lot"?

In certain areas, one might also estimate the average lot depth by half the distance between proximate streets?  But, generally, is there a good way to estimate a lot depth?  Does it matter?  Are 99% (?) of the houses in the U.S. within 100 feet from the street/geocode?

So, if we use the street line and the lateral boundaries posited above, and then 150 feet (obviously, to be tested/iterated) as the back of the box, and look for the footprints within the box, we will usually only find one footprint.  In the event of more than one footprint, flag the record to "ask Google", and do a new search starting from their pin?

Then, perhaps, any additional "non-obvious" cases, use the Google geocoder (which returns the lat/long of their pin in Google Maps?), to look for the nearest footprint?

Obviously, I am looking for better ideas or obvious solutions I may have overlooked.  Thanks in advance.